# Add [String, String] to UIAlertConroller message without Optional \"(Help)" in Swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, string, uialertcontroller

Below is a snippet of of code that allows me to show both strings in an UIAlertViewController message, However the Alert shows the strings with Optional brackets around them, can anyone help/know a better method to use other than the code below, Thanks in advance.

```
var show = [(String,String)]()

show.append(("our-Show", (OurUpdate?.theVersion)!))
show.append(("the-Show", (TheUpdate?.theVersion)!))

let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Updated", message:"\(show)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                let delay = 5.0 * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                let time = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time, execute: {

                    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
                })
```

[image]

Comment: Are you printing an array of tuples? message is an optional string

Comment: What should you display as a message? "our-show"/"the-show"?

Comment: Hey guys, I've updated with a screen shot of the Alert, just trying not to show the any brackets to be honest, what you think ?

Comment: as I told before, you are printing the entire array of tuples: you can access "our-show" using `show[0].0`, "1-5" using `show[0].1`, "the-Show" using `show[1].0`, etc. Anyway, I don't know what you are doing exactly, so it isn't easy to try to help you

Comment: And sorry, yea array of tuples, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using string interpolation to convert an array of tuples to a string. This is what is adding the square brackets, quotes, and parentheses. It's never a good idea to use string interpolation for anything except primitive types and other strings.

So the first step is to properly convert your array of tuple into a string in the format you actually want.

Here is one way:

```
let showStr = show.map { "\($0.0): \($0.1)" }.joined(separator: ", ")
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Updated", message: showStr, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
```

This will give the output:

> our-Show: 1-5, the-Show: 1-6

The use of `map` here is converting the array of tuples into an array of string where each string combines the two strings in the tuple and separates them with a colon. Then the `joined` call combines that new array of strings into one final string where each is separated by a comma.

Of course you can change this to format it any way you wish.

---

As a side note, the following code is dangerous:

```
show.append(("the-Show", (TheUpdate?.theVersion)!))
```

This code will crash if `TheUpdate` is `nil`. You really need to avoid force-unwrapping, especially when combined with optional chaining. A safer approach would be something like:

```
show.append(("the-Show", TheUpdate?.theVersion ?? "Some Default"))
```

where `"Some Default"` should be replaced with whatever value you to use incase `TheUpdate` is `nil`.

Comment: Nil coalescing is useful but I found myself distorting it, by passing empty strings, simply because in some cases the derived UX behavior is not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Better to use let syntax than using forced unwrapping. May the following code will help you:

```
if let ou = OurUpdate?.theVersion
{
    show.append(("our-Show", ou))
}
else
{
    show.append(("our-Show", "Error handling message!"))
}
```